# Bootstrap modal how to set backdrop?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap v3.2.0, i wish to change the backdrop to false after the modal have already initialized

i have try to use:

```
$('#myModal').removeData("modal").modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
```

but is not working, please help

Answer (score 2):

found answer

```
$('#modal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this compact way:

```
$('#modal').modal({ backdrop: "static" });
```